# How to use prefetch_related in django models

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have two models **Teachers** and **Subjects**. Don't worry about the names. It's just practice. I want to query All teachers and for each teacher, it will fetch all the subjects, he/she has created.

**Models**

```py
class Teachers(models.Model):
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    second = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class Subjects(models.Model):
    coursename = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    coursedescription = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    tutor = models.ForeignKey(
         Teachers, on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='teacher'
    )
```

I'm using **prefetch_related**

```py
teachers_subjects_queryset = Teachers.objects.prefetch_related('teacher').all()
```

What I'm getting after serializing

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "firstname": "Andrew",
    "second": "Njaya",
    "teacher": [
        1,
        2,
        3
    ]
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "firstname": "Kevin",
    "second": "Odhiambo",
    "teacher": [
        4,
        5
    ]}
```

What I want is

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "firstname": "Andrew",
    "second": "Njaya",
    "teacher": [
        {"id":1, "coursename":"Algebra", "coursedescription":"Fundermentals of Algebra"},
        {"id":2, "coursename":"Algebra", "coursedescription":"Fundermentals of Algebra"},
        {"id":3, "coursename":"Algebra", "coursedescription":"Fundermentals of Algebra"},
    ]
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "firstname": "Andrew",
    "second": "Njaya",
    "teacher": [
        {"id":4, "coursename":"Algebra", "coursedescription":"Fundermentals of Algebra"},
        {"id":5, "coursename":"Algebra", "coursedescription":"Fundermentals of Algebra"}
    ]}
```

Comment: Hi there, looks like your question is rather poorly worded and as such got a down-vote and you'll not get many replies. Here's some [https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask](official guidelines) on how to ask good questions.
However, I would suggest: 
1) Paste the relevant definition code of model, paste the code you used to query. 
2) Show what you're getting (snip to the relevant lines) and show what you would like to get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That looks like you are traversing model relationships in a serializer. [Check this out](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/)